# Postgis - migration from 1.5 to 2.3 - workaround

Tags: geometry, postgis

Fellows,

I already had a really hard time trying to make a migration from a postgis 1.5 to 2.3. Actually I had many attempts to do that with all version of postgis: 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 and now 2.3.

As I have spent a few weeks with that, and as I am ready to drop that I keep using my old version of postgresql and postgis, I hope my question finds a echo somewhere...

I only want to migrate one table field, a geometry field. So before trying to do that, I would like to hear if any of you have experience with that:

The idea is to select the field from the old postgis (postgresql 9.2, postgis 1.5), and update the table to the new postgis (postgresql 9.6, postgis 2.3).

Anyone can say anything about it?

EDIT---

I have just tryed to import the table I needed, but I got an error:
violation of constraint "enforce_srid_the_geom".

:(

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should accept fradal83's answer if it solves your problem,

Answer (score 0):

If you need to migrate just a single table with a geometry column and you are getting troubles with the procedure described here http://www.postgis.org/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade
I'd suggest a workaround: create a text field in the old db, e.g. wkt_geom, then execute

```
update tablename set wkt_geom = st_astext(the_geom)
```

Now drop the geometry column, export the old db and import into the new one. Then, create the geometry column and

```
update tablename set the_geom = st_geomfromtext(wkt_geom, SRID_HERE)
```

Comment: That seems very nice. But what would be the SRID_HERE?

Comment: The srid of your data. Try with: SELECT ST_SRID(the_geom) FROM your_table_name LIMIT 1; or select find_srid('schemaname', 'tablename', 'columnname');

Comment: The value of the first select is -1. The value of the second is an error: ERRO: find_srid() - couldnt find the corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?  Is there an uppercase/lowercase missmatch?
SQL state: P0001

Comment: You just don't have a SRID for that table, nor for geometries. Just remove the second parameter (SRID_HERE) of st_geomfromtext.